# Add an asterisk to the first child of the node with class

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an asterisk symbol before the label so that it looks like *Country based on the parent node with "required" class

```
  <span id="Country" class="none required">
  <label for="id_Country">Country</label>
    <select name="Country[]" id="id_Country">
       <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
       <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
    </select>
  </span>
```

I'm trying something like:

```
.required:first-child:before {
    content : "* ";
    color   : red;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A8KyK/

Comment: Please reformat your question into a question. Please state what problem(s) you are having.

Comment: I see an asterisk before the label in your fiddle. Whats the problem?

Comment: The fiddle is *exactly* the code from his post.

Comment: oh... i see lulz all around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to apply the `*` before the `label`, then you need to use the CSS selector as follows:

```
.required > label:first-child:before {
    content : "* ";
    color   : red;
}
```

The `:first-child` selector applies to the actual element it is modifying. In other words, it needs to be read as "apply this css before the label that is the first-child to it's parent. This parent must also have a class of required" not "apply this css before the first-child of node with required as class" as is done in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the selector incorrectly, `first-child` [definition](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html):

> The :first-child pseudo class means "if this element is the first child of its parent".

Which in your case translates to "if `.required` is the *first child of its parent*".  I don't think that's what you're intending.

How about:

```
$('label', '.required').prepend('*');
```

Cheers